# Android studio doesn't show "&" symbol in String

Tags: android, xml, string, android-studio

When I try to write the `&` symbol in a string like `&` it just leaves the place white. I get no errors or anything, it's just that it isn't shown.
Anyone know how to solve this?[image]

"This is a string `&` here is the `&` symbol"

Comment: Do you get a picture?

Comment: I dont know what you exactly meant by that but I added a picture to clarify

Comment: it seems your keyboard doesn't match your operating system configuration

Answer (score 1):

you can write `&` using:

`&amp;`

or

`\u0026`

like this:

```
"this is a string &amp; symbol"
```

or

```
"this is a string \u0026 symbol"
```

result: this is a string & symbol

Answer (score 0):

Use encoding `&amp;` or `\u0026` to show the `&` symbol in android!